# Maintain size of application to 1 mb?

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to make an iOS application and I don't want the size of application more than 1 MB. As per my previous experience application size increased because assets which we have used. is there any best way to handle assets which will not affect in size of an application. is there other parameters in an application which we can consider for minimizing the size.

Comment: Honestly, how can one answer such a question. I have an app with an icon, three targets, other images... and it's 32.2 MB. Easily accepted in the App Store. Why are you trying to maintain such a small size? And can you give us some details as to what this app is?

Comment: Well, you can use [App thinning](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html) feature, but whats the reason for keeping size smaller than 1mb? It doesnt seems matter

Comment: @dfd, I agree with you, it's our customer suggestion can we make application size 1 MB. As per my knowledge, we can't do. but I just want to confirm if there is any way to do that which I don't know. Thanks for quick reply.

Comment: If your are using more images in your assets, as per my understanding there is no way to decrease size.... Size increase if you use more assets images, some third party library etc....

Comment: While a very unscientific test, I created a new single-view project built it and ran it. No icon, no assets, nothing but a blank white screen written in, uh, Swift 3.0. Checked out the app some. It's 16.9 MB.